# Swift: How to set horizontal back and forth movements on a sprite?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm looking to add an image (shape) back and forth on the screen forever.

I want the image to stop when you tap on the screen.

I found some codes but they are all in objective C and I even tried to make it to swift but couldn't figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using SpriteKit then you can create actions that move the sprite from the right to the left and back forever.

```
let moveLeft = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: xPosition, y:  yPosition), duration: duration)
let moveRight = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: xPosition, y:  yPosition), duration: duration)

sprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([moveLeft, moveRight])))
```

Then to stop it from moving you can use this code:

```
sprite.removeAllActions()
```